# Django : on_delete=models.SET.NULL gives error

Tags: python, django, django-models

Why attribute in my model class where

```
class Tour_Cart(models.Model):

tours=models.ForeignKey(Tours,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
```

Throws error:

**AttributeError**: 'function' object has no attribute 'NULL'

Why so?

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just missing on `SET.NULL`, it should be `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `on_delete=models.CASCADE`?

Also you're missing `(models.Model)` from your class declaration.

Comment: I don't think you can set a Foreign key to null... try removing `null=True`